# Linq tables relations wierd issue?

Tags: linq, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am having a problem with the tables relations in LINQ since it generates all property by it self, i have several tables with one(A) -> many(B) relation, and the weird thing is that when i access the object B, i can see the tbl_A which i am not suppose to, thus generating an error which i have been struggling for hours until i noticed it. Here is the schema:

[image]

What i want now is to make the realtions right, meaning that the user can see the city, but the city can't see the user, and like that cause now the city can see the user and vice versa.

Solution:

*Click on the association arrow.

*On the property window, switch the child property to false.

Answer (score 0):

By default, LINQ will expose all relational properties in either direction. If you want to continue using the automatically generated code then there's no real way to get rid of it completely.. the only solution I know of is to change the accessibility of the property to `protected` or `private` (not sure if `private` will break things though).

Comment: there is only public and internal ?

Comment: My apologies... it's been awhile since I've used LINQ (using Entity Framework now days). I looked at my last LINQ code and I'm actually using `internal` on the accessibility and have the LINQ classes in a data access library.